# How to Create a List of Different Enum Classes

Tags: java, enums

I'd like to create a list of different Enum classes and be able to access the values of these enums in the list. For instance, consider two Enums:

```
enum Enum1 {
  ENUM1_VALUE_1, ENUM1_VALUE_2;
}

enum Enum2 {
  ENUM2_VALUE_1, ENUM2_VALUE_2;
}
```

I'd like to construct a list of Enum1 and Enum2 such that I can print the values of Enum1 and Enum2.

It would look something like this, but this obviously doesn't compile:

```
List<Enum> enumList = Arrays.asList(Enum1, Enum2);
for (Enum enumEntry: enumList) {
    System.out.println(enumList.values());
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mixing enum objects

Have both classes implement the same interface, with any methods you need.

Then create your list containing objects of that interface rather than of either enum class.

Tip: As of Java 16, interfaces, enum, and records can be defined locally.

```java
interface Animal {}

enum Pet implements Animal { DOG, CAT ; }
enum Wild implements Animal { LION , ORCA ; }

List< Animal > felines = List.of( Pet.CAT , Wild.LION ) ;
```

## Mixing enum classes

If the *class* of the enum is what you want to collect, use the [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) class.

```
List< Class > myEnumClasses = List.of( Pet.class , Wild.class ) ;
```

Enums in Java implicitly extend the `Enum` class. So we can be more specific with our type of list.

```
List < Class < ? extends Enum > > myEnumClasses = List.of( Pet.class , Wild.class );
```

> myEnumClasses.toString(): [class demo.App$1Pet, class demo.App$1Wild]

Regarding the last part, your ultimate goal of looping the `Enum` classes to invoke the implicit `Enum` method `public static T[] values()` on each… Use a special method found on the `Class` class: [`getEnumConstants`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()). That method returns an array of the enum’s objects.

For convenience, we can pass that array to `List.of` to easily generate a textual representation of the enum objects by calling `List#toString`.

```java
for ( Class < ? extends Enum > e : myEnumClasses )
{
    System.out.println( "e = " + e );
    System.out.println( List.of( e.getEnumConstants() ) );  // Pass the array T[] to `List.of` for convenient printing.
}
```

When run.

```
e = class demo.App$1Pet
[DOG, CAT]
e = class demo.App$1Wild
[LION, ORCA]
```

Comment: Yes, this could work in theory, but it may defeat the purpose of having an Enum. Because I don't believe I could create an object that is both an Enum and also implements the common interface that I define. EDIT: Thank you for providing an example, however I'm hoping to have an implementation that avoids having to list the Enum values. In other words, I'd like to construct a list of PET and WILD and be able to access a method (hopefully static ```values``` method) to list all of their values.

Comment: @user699279 See my edits.

Comment: Mixing Enum classes was my use case, and it worked perfectly! Thank you for the help. However, I will mention that a ```List<Enum>``` wouldn't compile. At least for me, on Java 11, it had to be a ```List<Class<? extends Enum>>```

Comment: @user699279 Thanks for the feedback. I have not yet mastered the subtleties of Java generics such as `? extends`. I fixed the Answer. Also, I found `Class#getEnumConstants` is the key to getting the objects of each of our `Enum` subclasses. I updated the example code to suit.